# automatically trigger one of the submit buttons in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form as follows:

```
<form name="dummyform" id="dummyform">
  <input type="text" name="dummyname">
  <input type="submit" name="save_as_draft" id`="save_as_draft">
  <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" hidden>
  <button name="Dummysend" id="Dummysend">SEND DUMMY</button>
</form>
```

I want to trigger only the button with id `send` automatically when I click on the button with id `Dummysend`. I can do this by doing this JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById("dummyform").submit();
```

The problem is that there are two submit buttons in this form. How can I only trigger the submit button with id `send`?

Comment: @panther gived you the answer, and when executing `document.getElementById("send").click();` this will trigger only the submit of that specific button, Meaning on the server side received post data you will not have the property/key of the others buttons, thats how html form submission works

Answer (score 1):

By input `name`, `ID`, context...

For example:

`document.getElementById("send").click();`

Answer (score -2):

Watch out for your HTML too it has some syntax errors:

- The 'action' attribute is required for  elements.
- 'id`' is not a valid attribute of the  element.

Comment: Eh? id` is obviously typo in here. But it doesn't cause the problem, id` is just ignored as attribute, it's just a mess. `action` isn't required, when `action` is missing, form is sent to the same page.

Comment: The `action` attribute is [optional](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fs-action) on `<form>` elements. If it's not specified, [`action` is the URL of the form document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-submission-algorithm).